# Multi column dropdown menu inline block not working

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a multicolumn dropdown menu that it loads dynamically with django. I use django templeting for tag, and it seems to be adding spaces on column heights. 
The menu is divided in 4 columns, and shows categories and sub-categories. Some categories have sub-categories ( 1 or many ) and some don't.

```
                <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Prods<b class="caret"></b></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu row">
                           {%for c in categ %}
                            <li class="col-sm-3">
                                <ul>                      
                                <li><a href="/">{{c.name}}</a></li>
                            {% for s in sub_cat %}                                   
                                <li><a href="/">{{s.name}}</a></li>                              
                            {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <li class="col-sm-3">
                                <ul>  
                                <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="/>All</a>/li>
                                </ul>  
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Here is what I get in the first picture, and what I need to achieve in the second.

[image: This is what I get]

[image: this is what I need to achieve]

Comment: You'll probably have to use something like http://masonry.desandro.com/ to achieve your required layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using masonry js http://masonry.desandro.com/ I was able to achieve your desired layout. You wont be able to do this just using the bootstrap grid, as the floated divs don't work that way.

The biggest thing to notice here is the structure of the html in the dropdown nav - So you will have to make some relatively minor changes to the way the subnav is populated.

example:

```
<li class=" grid-item"><a href="/">Cat 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Sub 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Sub 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

For the grid i've used percentages for the columns, as that is how the bootstrap grid works, so i've assumed this is for use on a responsive site? If not you can supply fixed pixel widths instead. You will have to supply some form of fixed measurement on the dropdown nav though, or at least a min-width option as it is absolutely positioned.

For this to work you have to initialise the grid javascript when the dropdown nav is visible, otherwise the js used to position each item just wont work.

```
$('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () { ...
```

More info on the bootstrap dropdown is available here: 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

you should however give your dropdown an ID and then use this in the javscript instead, otherwise it could cause some problems if you have more than the one dropdown instance on your site.

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/BKNrBb

Refer to the masonry documentation for more information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that realy helped ! I have managed to make it work but it isnt responsive. I want to be one column on small screens just like normal bootstrap menu. I have added @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {   .grid-sizer { width: 10%;  } } but doesnt work as expected.

Comment: Just added width 100% to grid and grid-item and now seems to be working on small screens.